# Clickhouse Cannot parse input: expected \t before

Tags: python, clickhouse

I am trying to insert data into clickhouse using yandex logs api (https://github.com/yndx-metrika/logs_api_integration)
It uses `requests` as a library to send request.

My error is:

```
Code: 27, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected \t before: \n33\t55\t2017-05-05\n33\t55\t2017-05-05\n33\t55\t2017-05-05\n33\t55\t2017-05-05 (version 19.16.4.12)
```

While I am sending request, my query params are:

```
{u'query': u'INSERT INTO db.table FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNames ', u'input_format_allow_errors_num': 99999, u'input_format_tsv_empty_as_default': 1, u'input_format_allow_errors_ratio': 1}
```

engine is MergeTree()

columns are not Nullable

My data is

```
ClientID  CounterID  Date
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
55  33  2017-05-05
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure the number of columns (and columns names/types itself) you try to insert are the same in the destination table

Answer (score 1):

When used [TabSeparatedWithNames](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#tabseparatedwithnames) it needs to pass the header (column names):

```py
import requests

CH_USER = 'default'
CH_PASSWORD = ''
SSL_VERIFY = False

host = 'http://localhost:8123'
db = 'db'
table = 'table'

content = 'ClientID\tCounterID\tDate' \
          '\n33\t55\t2017-05-05' \
          '\n33\t55\t2017-05-05' \
          '\n33\t55\t2017-05-05' \
          '\n33\t55\t2017-05-05' \
          '\n33\t55\t2017-05-05'
content = content.encode('utf-8')
query_dict = {
    'query': 'INSERT INTO ' + db + '.' + table + ' FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNames '
}

r = requests.post(host, data=content, params=query_dict, auth=(CH_USER, CH_PASSWORD), verify=SSL_VERIFY)

print(r.text)
```

---

Test table schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table
(
    `ClientID` Int32,
    `CounterID` Int32,
    `Date` date
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY Date
```